# Foreign currency to Excel xslt

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I am trying to create an xslt file that will take currency values in either EUR, JPY, GBP or USD and present them in an Excel output. To do this, I have created the following condition to capture the currency:

```
    <Style ss:ID="s63">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test='$currency = "EUR"'>
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="_(&quot;€&quot;\ * #,##0.00_);_(&quot;€&quot;\ * \(#,##0.00\);_(&quot;€&quot;\ * &quot;-&quot;??_);_(@_)"/>
    </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:when test='$currency = "JPY"'>
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="_(&quot;¥&quot;\ * #,##0.00_);_(&quot;€&quot;\ * \(#,##0.00\);_(&quot;€&quot;\ * &quot;-&quot;??_);_(@_)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test='$currency = "GBP"'>
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="_-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;\-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* &quot;-&quot;??_-;_-@_-"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <NumberFormat ss:Format="&quot;$&quot;#,##0.00"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </Style>
```

This actually works quite well. As expected, I am getting the appropriate currency symbol. The problem I am having is with EUR. For some reason all of my currency values are getting multiplied by 100. I suspect it has something to do with the incoming format for EUR being in ###.###,00 format, going to #,##0.00 format. I can't get Excel to take ###.###,00 as a valid format, though. Does anyone know how I can keep my currency from multiplying? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with *formatting*? How are the actual values populated?

Comment: *I suspect it has something to do with the incoming format for EUR being in ###.###,00 format.* That can't work, excel needs an unformated number to apply its own formatting to it. If you use `format-number()` on your input values, don't.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I basically need to treat the incoming values as a string since Excel doesn't like the #.###,00 format. So first I cast the value to a number in the correct format by:

```
    <xsl:variable name="extCost" select="number(translate(extendedCost_line,'###.##0,00','###0.00'))"></xsl:variable>
```

Once I have my variable set, then I can format my number:

```
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63">
    <Data ss:Type="Number"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(($extCost div 100), '#,##0.00', 'american')" /></Data>
    </Cell>
```

This has forced me to create a row loop specific to EUR currency, and another row loop to capture all other currencies. This ends up giving me a number where the euro symbol appears before the number, but the formatting of the number is using a comma as the thousands separator and a period as a decimal point. The spreadsheet I'm creating is not customer-facing, so that is not an issue.

Thanks to those who commented! Hopefully this will help anyone facing the same challenge I was.

Comment: This `translate(extendedCost_line,'###.##0,00','###0.00')` makes no sense and when it works, it's purely by accident. It will **not** work when the number contains a thousands separator dot. IIUC, you need to replace the decimal comma with a dot, and remove the thousands separator dot, i.e. `translate(extendedCost_line,',.','.')`.